# Unable to connect Memcached in over-too visitor

Tags: php, centos, memcached, centos7, disconnect

I use Php & Memcache on Centos 7.  Memcache not have log file but create  me memcache connection status on mysql.

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
if(!($memcache->connect('localhost', 11211))){
    $date_er= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    mysql_query("insert into memcacheerror (date_er,ip) values('$date','$ip')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

When I check the table now, there are about 953 connections that do not connect , about ~5 hours..

Memcache status log -> *watch "echo stats | nc 127.0.0.1 11211"*

```
STAT pid 12939
STAT uptime 60708
STAT time 1489228368
STAT version 1.4.15
STAT libevent 2.0.21-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 49.208000
STAT rusage_system 181.028000
STAT curr_connections 10
STAT total_connections 1510442
STAT connection_structures 83
STAT reserved_fds 20
STAT cmd_get 2578565
STAT cmd_set 3716
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 2574844
STAT get_misses 3721
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 76806965
STAT bytes_written 17519935942
STAT limit_maxbytes 2147483648
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
```

Memcache config file

```
PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="5024"
CACHESIZE="2048"
OPTIONS=""
```

How do I solve this problem? What is the solution ? Really thank you for now.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem. Solution increase sysctl nf_conntrack_max.

Check max and current value

cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_count

last, increase nf_conntrack_max value.

echo "556546" > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max